# Main Activity go to background as a result of morphing animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, morphing

I have multiple Activities includes multiple fragments. I try to display morphing animation from a RecyclerView item in 1st fragment to an ImageView in 2nd fragment. 1st fragment go to background (it becomes a bit dark) and when I return back from 2nd fragment, when View lays out in its place in RecyclerView, 1st fragment comes to foreground (it becomes lighter). It looks like a blinking in whole screen.

In 1st Activity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
        setExitSharedElementCallback(
            MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback()
        )
}
```

In 1st fragment :

```
override fun onClick(t: T, poster: View) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, DetailActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtras(Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable(EXTRA_TMDB_ITEM, t)
                putParcelable(EXTRA_NAV_TYPE, navType)
            })
        }
        val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            activity,
            poster, t.name
        )
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
    }
```

in 2nd Activity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)

        // set up shared element transition
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(
            MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback()
        )
        window.sharedElementEnterTransition = getContentTransform()
        window.sharedElementReturnTransition = getContentTransform()
}

/** get a material container arc transform. */
    private fun getContentTransform(): MaterialContainerTransform {
        return MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            addTarget(R.id.details_poster)
            duration = 450
            pathMotion = MaterialArcMotion()
        }
    }
```

in 2nd fragment :

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.detailsPoster, tmdbItem.name)
}
```

Source code can be found here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Paging

Do you know how can I avoid 1st fragment in 1st Activity go to background?